# Emulator won't update

Tags: cordova, bower, ionic-framework

I'm running the iconic platform for development and I change the files in my editor then I rebuild the android app but everything stays the same, the changes have no effect.

Images will update but not text files.

I've tried running cordova and it still won't update the emulator
I've tried clearing the npm and bower cache

I can access all the files but and change then but the emulator won't

I also have  bower installed

Comment: What browser are you using?  Also, there are issues with code being cached; are you using cachebusting for your JavaScript? (by appending `?v={{randomNumber}}` to your JavaScript).  If you're having that problem and are still using Cachebusting to update the JavaScript between changes, then we need to see code / setup that reproduces this issue.

Comment: I'm using the android emulator and Chrome

Comment: I think this is a fair question. The specific technical problem JohnnyQ is having doesn't require much more detail then he originally provided. I would bet George's comment lends well for this specific question. I would also agree that it sounds like an caching issue - but it's strange since images update, but text doesn't.  I would check the built-in Google Chrome Developer Tools  to profile which items might be being cached/not-changed, ensure all the resource requests have 200 status and also turn off all caching (disable cache) on the network tab. This might lead you the solution.

Comment: It is possible that the platform/www directory isn't updated accordingly. Try ionic build android and check in platforms/android/www whether the necessary files have been changed. If not, delete the platforms/android/www folder manually and rebuild the app. Also, if deploying via Android Developer Tools (Eclipse), you have to clean the build to make Eclipse detect the changes and rebuild/deploy.

Comment: As I can't see the option to answer the question myself (probably because it's on hold) this is the reason why. I had installed the latest version of node.js which was v0.12.2 this version can cause issues with npm install package I uninstalled v0.12.2 and installed an earlier version v0.10.2 and then npm was able to function correctly and run sass which fixed the problem of why the content was not updating.

Comment: Fastest way for me is to uninstall and then install app again.